# Conditional probability (sum of two independent random variables)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a simple question about probability. Three variables $X$, $W$ and $Y$ with pdfs $f_X(x), f_W(w)$ and $f_Y(y)$, where $Y=X+W$ and $X$ and $W$ are independent.

My question is: how to express $E(W^2)$ (expectation) in terms of $x$ and $y$, one paper points out that $$E(W^2)=\iint (y-x)^2 f_X(x) f_W(y-x) dx dy$$
How to get this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mimiga,

Since $W=Y-X$, we can write $E(W^2)=\int W^2f_W(W)dW=\int (y-x)^2f_W(W)dW$ (this actually doesn't make sense yet but I couldn't find a better way to explain it). So we get $$\int (y-x)^2f_W(W)dW=\int \left(\int (y-x)^2f_W(y-x)dy\right)f_X(x)dx$$ This is because since $W=Y-X$, to do the integral on the left hand side, it is equal to first integrating $(y-x)^2f_W(y-x)$ with respect to $y$, then taking the expected value with respect to $x$. Now, by Fubini we get: 
$$\int \left(\int (y-x)^2f_W(y-x)dy\right)f_X(x)dx=\int\int (y-x)^2f_X(x)f_W(y-x)dx dy$$

I hope this helps!

Comment: How about taking w.r.t $x$ first and then $y$, for example, $$\int \left(\int (y-x)^2 f_W(y-x)dx\right)f_Y(y)dy$$

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but since $Y=X+W$ is the sum of two independent random variables, we have that $f_Y=f_W *f_X$ i.e. the convolution of $f_W$ and $f_X$. Substituting this, I believe you should get the same answer.

Comment: The above equation can be expanded to $$\iint (y-x)^2 f_Y(y) f_W(y-x)dxdy$$ and the only difference is to replace $f_X(x)$ by $f_Y(y)$. So I do not think these two have the same answer. So maybe your derivation has some mistakes or the paper just points out the wrong expression?